# Upgrade Facebook Graph API Version

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am having an android app, which when I debug makes calls to graph.facebook.com/2.7 which means it points to Graph API version 2.7.

But in my "Upgrade API Version" in Advanced settings point to 2.9. What does this mean?

Does this mean that even though my client makes call to 2.7 its upgraded to 2.9?

Do I need to upgrade my SDK or can I live without it?

Comment: Yes, that’s exactly what that means. Your app might still specify v2.7 in it’s API calls, but this setting overwrites that, so that it behaves as if you had called v2.9 explicitly to begin with.

Comment: Great. Can you point me to a doc or something where it tells that the call is upgraded based on what we provide in "Upgrade API Version" ?